# Page not refreshing on nested ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I added a new client using JQuery dialog and on success I want to reload the page but not happening.

### JQuery call

```
 $("#saveNewClient").click(function () 
        {
            if ($(this).valid())
            {
                var clientName = null;
                var clientTypeId = null;
                var clientCode = null;

                clientName = $('#Client_ClientName').val();
                clientTypeId = $('#ClientTypeSelectId').val();
                clientCode = $('#Client_ClientCode').val();

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "/Client/AddClient",
                        cache: false,
                        data: { "clientName": clientName, "clientTypeId": clientTypeId, "clientCode": clientCode },
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (request) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            //alert('Successfully Inserted Client');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Client/Index",
                                type: 'GET',
                                datatype: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    //alert('got here with data');
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    //alert('something bad happened');
                                }
                            });
                            $('#myClientDialogContainer').dialog('close');
                        }
                    });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Earlier I given an alert message "Successfully added client". But as the client added is not appearing in the grid. I called another ajax call to refresh the page with the data. The action method is calling and when the page loads I can see the the added client data is passing to Grid, but  the grid is not appearing with the newly inserted client. When I refresh the page the row is appearing. Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in your success callback you refresh your DOM:

```
success: function (data) {
    //alert('got here with data');
    $('#yourGridContainer').html(data);
}
```

This obviously assumes that the `Index` controller action is returning a partial view containing the grid with the updated results.

Comment: My grid is inside a div called grid and I given the same as above but not working. Now the add new dialog is not closing and it stays on. ie, $('#grid).html(data);

Comment: Is your `Index` controller action returning a partial view with the grid contents? Also what do you see in FireBug? Is the AJAX request being sent? What does the server return? Are there some errors in the console?

Comment: Index controller action is not returning a partial view. But it returns View(model) and grid is placed in a div="grid" in this page itself. Yes the AJAX request being send and I got the commented out alert above in the code ('got here with data'). I can see the data populated on the load of this page. But the grid is not appearing with the newly added client.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. You should call a controller action which is returning a partial view containing your grid.

Comment: Thanks Darin. Currently grid is not a partial view. Even if it is not partial the data is populating in the page load of index.cshtml and passing the actual data on the Webgrid initialization in the beginning. As I told earlier the grid is placed in a div tag in this page itself.

Comment: Alright, but as I told you if you want to perform a refresh using AJAX, your controller action need to return a partial view.

Comment: Darin, I made the Grid as partial view but still not working and controller action I am returning PartailView with the name and model as parameters. I can see the AJAX call go to controller and came back in PartialView with the data which i entered. But in the grid the data is not appearing. But when I refresh the page data is showing in grid.

Comment: What do you see in FireBug? Is the AJAX request being sent? What does the server return? Are there some errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The AJAX request being send and the partial class is loaded and I can see the added client data being populated. But not appearing in the grid.

Comment: Darin, when I specify your first comment $('#yourGridContainer').html(data); and put in WebGrid initialization when I put ajaxupdateContainerId as "grid" as below it is working fine. Thanks for all the help. var grid = new WebGrid(clients, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");